# Returning wx.Panel from threading.Thread subclass

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

i have a subclass from threading.Thread that i use to create wx.Panels (because most of them are I/O bound) and sending them via wx.PostEvent to my wx.Frame.

The problem is that after the thread is over, the panel that was sent is destroyed and lost, leaving the frame blank. i believe that this is linked to the fact that the thread itself is destroyed after executing. Adding time.sleep(s) to the last line of the thread allows to see the panel inside the frame for s seconds, while the thread is frozen, proving that the panel was in fact created.

Here's the code for the frame that may interess you:

```
self.Bind(MyEvents.EVT_CONTROL_NEWPANEL,self.ChangePanel)
def ChangePanel(self,event):
    if self.panel != None:
        self.panel.Hide()
    self.panel = event.panel
    self.panel.Show()
```

and the one for the threading.thread subclass:

```
class ThreadExecute(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func,args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        apply(self.func,self.args)

CreateRandomPanel(parent):
    panel = RandomPanel(parent)
    event = MyEvents.Control_NewPanel(panel = panel)
    wx.PostEvent(parent,event)
```

Is there a way to keep the object alive after the thread is over?
Is pickling the object on the Thread and depickling it on the frame a good alternative?

**Edited:**

A small runable example of the code:

```
import wx
import threading
from wx.lib.newevent import NewEvent
from time import sleep

NewPanelEvent, EVT_NEWPANEL = NewEvent()
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,size=wx.Size(350,350))
        self.panel = None        
        self.Bind(EVT_NEWPANEL,self.ChangePanel)
        self.control = MyControl(self)
        self.control.NewPanel()

    def ChangePanel(self,event):

        if self.panel != None:
            self.panel.Hide()

        self.panel = event.panel
        #self.Refresh()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=size)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self,label='hit me!',pos=wx.Point(25,25),size=wx.Size(75,25))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,0))

class MyControl(object):
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window

    def NewPanel(self):
        MyThread(RandomFunction,(self.window,))

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func,args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        apply(self.func,self.args)

def RandomFunction(window):
    sleep(3)
#    size = window.GetSizeTuple()
    size = (250,250) 
    panel = MyPanel(window,size=size)
    event = NewPanelEvent(panel = panel)
    wx.PostEvent(window,event)
    # use the sleep to prevent the thread from ending, so you can see the panel
    sleep(5)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you actually pass the RandomPanel anywhere. You create it and then when the function ends, it gets destroyed. You never actually pass the panel, but just the parent. Personally, I would use wx.CallAfter to send a PubSub message to your main application class and have it create a panel there or just pass the panel in the PubSub message.

Here's a tutorial on Pubsub:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

And here's one with pubsub and threads:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: The panel is passed as an attribute of event
<<event = MyEvents.Control_NewPanel(panel = panel)>>

The EvtHandler can obtain the panel object using event.panel

As for the wx.CallAfter, its built over wx.PostEvent, so i guess passing the panel using it would cause the same error, but i will try later.

Comment: I guess I need a small runnable example to see why that doesn't work